# What's the criteria for an application to be included in the Universe repository?

Tags: development, application-development, official-repositories

I started a hobby project and figured that if there were some reasonably reachable criteria for this, I might as well work in that direction. Tried asking on #ubuntu-app-devel, but the channel seems kinda dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find official information here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu you have a 'better' option. Have a look at this [Launchpad page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) about packaging.

That way you can tell people to add your PPA [(explanation and examples here)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) into Ubuntu Software Center and install it from there.

Comment: I know that (and planning to do it), but I'm specifically interested in inclusion in the Universe repository.